# Can plugins add functions to AssetFileModel?

Tags: plugin-development

I am currently working on a Craft CMS plugin, which adds functionality on top of assets, that should be callable in templates. I have come up with a Twig Extension that allows templates to call it like this:

```
{{ image | myCustomMethod }}
```

However, I would like to provide the method directly on the image itself instead (because it is more readable/intuitive and makes sure `image` is included in the craft element cache):

```
{{ image.myCustomMethod() }}
```

Is it possible for a plugin to extend the AssetFileModel class to do that? If so, how?